# Android - Imageviews make them visible again, dont work

Tags: android, visible

I have a problem with my ImageViews.
At a certain time I disable it and make it invisible. Later in the program, but they should be re-enabled and visible. Unfortunately it does not work. I have often tried to find the bug with the debugger, but the corresponding code is not skipped. Nevertheless, the buttons in the app are not visible or enabled. Even the animated drawable does not start, even though it should. This should happen when calling from playanimation().

As this is my first app or program, the code is a bit unreadable.

Maybe can help me? 
Here's the code:

I mean that part of the code:

```
case 1:
                imageViewsleepbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageViewfeedbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageViewShowerbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageViewPlaybutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageViewsleepbutton.setEnabled(true);
                imageViewfeedbutton.setEnabled(true);
                imageViewShowerbutton.setEnabled(true);
                imageViewPlaybutton.setEnabled(true);
                Settings.setLevel(2, context);
                helper.setCorrectPet();
                helper.playAnimation();
                textviewStatus.setText(activity.getString(R.string.baby));
                break;
```

In that class:

```
package at.android.virtualpet;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TimerC{

    //TODO Try-Catch Timer
    private Handler handler;
    Toast toast;

    private ImageView imageViewsleepbutton;
    private ImageView imageViewfeedbutton;
    private ImageView imageViewShowerbutton;
    private ImageView imageViewPlaybutton;
    private TextView textviewStatus;

    private int intervall;

    private Helper helper;

    private Context context;
    Activity activity;

    public TimerC(Context context, Activity activity, int intervall){
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.intervall = intervall;
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        boolean b, resume;
        b = Settings.getFirstStart(context);
        resume = Settings.getResumeStatus(context);
        handler = new Handler();

        helper = new Helper(context, activity);

        if (b == true) {
            Settings.setFirstStart(false, context);
            handler.postDelayed(timedTask, 45000); //45000
        }
        else {
            if (resume == true) {
                helper.resumeStats();
                Settings.setResumeStatus(false, context);
        }
        handler.postDelayed(timedTask, intervall);
        }
    }

    public void stopTimer() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(timedTask);
    }

    private void changePet() {
        int stufe;
        int progress;

        imageViewsleepbutton = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewsleepbutton);
        imageViewfeedbutton = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageViewfeedbutton);
        textviewStatus = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.textViewStatus);
        imageViewShowerbutton = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageViewShowerButton);
        imageViewPlaybutton = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPlayButton);

        stufe = Settings.getLevel(context);
        progress = Settings.getLevelProgress(context);

        if (progress <= 0 || stufe == 1) {
            switch(stufe) {
            case 1:
                imageViewsleepbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageViewfeedbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageViewShowerbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageViewPlaybutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageViewsleepbutton.setEnabled(true);
                imageViewfeedbutton.setEnabled(true);
                imageViewShowerbutton.setEnabled(true);
                imageViewPlaybutton.setEnabled(true);
                Settings.setLevel(2, context);
                helper.setCorrectPet();
                helper.playAnimation();
                textviewStatus.setText(activity.getString(R.string.baby));
                break;
            case 2:
                Settings.setLevel(3, context);
                helper.setCorrectPet();
                helper.playAnimation();
                textviewStatus.setText(activity.getString(R.string.teen));
                break;
            case 3:
                Settings.setLevel(4, context);
                helper.setCorrectPet();
                helper.playAnimation();
                textviewStatus.setText(activity.getString(R.string.adult));
                break;
            }
            Settings.setLevelProgress(1000, context);
        }
    }

    private void changeStats() {
        int hunger;
        int progress;
        int stufe;
        int sleep;
        int fun;
        int dirty;
        int level;
        int xp;

        boolean day;
        boolean firststart;

        Random randInt = new Random();

        int promp = 1; //progress multiplikator
        int minushunger = randInt.nextInt(4)+3;
        int minussleep = 3;
        int sleepnight = 15;
        int hungernight = randInt.nextInt(3)+2;
        int minusdirty = randInt.nextInt(4)+2;
        int minusfun = randInt.nextInt(2)+2;
        int dirtynight = minusdirty;
        int funnight = minusfun;

        hunger = Settings.getHunger(context);
        progress = Settings.getLevelProgress(context);
        fun = Settings.getFun(context);
        dirty = Settings.getDirty(context);
        stufe = Settings.getLevel(context);
        sleep = Settings.getSleep(context);
        level = Settings.getLevel(context);
        firststart = Settings.getFirstStart(context);
        xp = Settings.getXP(context);

        day = Settings.getDay(context);

        if ((firststart == false) && (level != 1)) {

            if (day == true) {
                hunger = hunger - minushunger;
                sleep = sleep - minussleep;
                dirty = dirty - minusdirty;
                fun = fun - minusfun;
            } else {
                hunger = hunger - hungernight;
                sleep = sleep + sleepnight;
                dirty = dirty - dirtynight;
                fun = fun - funnight;
            }

            if(sleep > 100) {
                sleep = 100;
                helper.wakeup();
            }

            if(hunger < -5 ) {hunger = -5;}
            if(sleep < -5) {sleep = -5;}            
            if(hunger > 110) {hunger = 110;}
            if(dirty < -15 ) {dirty = -15;}
            if(fun < -15 ) {fun = -15;}
            if(dirty > 110) {dirty = 110;}
            if(fun > 110) {fun = 110;}

            Settings.setSleep(sleep, context);
            Settings.setHunger(hunger, context);
            Settings.setDirty(dirty, context);
            Settings.setFun(fun, context);

            //promp = 1
            if ((sleep < 0) && (hunger < 0) && (dirty < 20) && (fun < 20)) {promp = 0;};
            if ((sleep > 90) && (hunger > 90) && (dirty > 75) && (fun > 75)) {promp = 2;};


            switch(stufe) {
            case 1:
                //Stufe 1 ist Ei. Das Ei schlüpft automatisch nach x Sek
                break;
            case 2:
                progress = progress - (5 * promp);
                break;
            case 3:
                progress = progress - (4 * promp);
                break;
            case 4:
                progress = progress - (3 * promp);
                break;
            }
            xp = xp + 4*promp;
            Settings.setXP(xp, context);
            helper.setCorrectPet();
            helper.checkLevel();
            Settings.setLevelProgress(progress, context);
            helper.checkStatus();
        }

    }


    private Runnable timedTask = new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run() {
              changePet();
              changeStats(); //Werte ändern und Meldungen ausgeben
              helper.updateprogress();
              helper.updateDebugFields();
              handler.postDelayed(timedTask, intervall);
          }};
}
```

and the playanimation() in an other class. This class has context an the activity from MainActivity.

```
public void playAnimation() {
    imageViewPet = (ImageView)activity.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPet);
    if (imageViewPet.getDrawable() instanceof AnimationDrawable) {
        animatedaotori = (AnimationDrawable)imageViewPet.getDrawable();
        Handler handler = new Handler(activity.getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                animatedaotori.start();             
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked outside the switch. in debugger mode, the case 1 is called. I dont understand.